# Android: hyperlink textview to a map location?

Tags: android, dictionary, hyperlink, location

I read the documents of Linkify and know how to make a Hyperlink Textview and open browser when user clicks on it, but is there anyway to make a textview(also with a hyperlink look, blue and clickable) but actually shows a map with a pinned location when user clicks on it, for example, in a table:

### Hotel ABC

location   [some address]

"some address" appears to be a link, but when you click it, instead of showing a web, it shows you a map with the actually address pinned?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The native Android Google Maps app (if available on device) will respond to standard http://maps.google.com URLs and query strings, so something like the following will work:

```
TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytextview);
t.setText(Html.fromHtml(
   "Location " +
   "<a href=\"http://maps.google.com/maps?q=1+Infinite+Loop,+Cupertino,+Santa+Clara,+California+95014\">" + 
   "1 Infinite Loop, Cupertino, Santa Clara, California 95014" +
   "</a>"));
t.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: Thanks! Also, is it possible to handle the link click event as I need to use fragment(other than Activity) for it?

Comment: If you're needing to handle the clicks yourself then I would probably forget about linkifying and just use a standard View onClick handler method to fire the appropriate intent.

Comment: Nice, but it does not function for me. Are there permissions to give to app on maninfest?